# GzipResponseWriter field declaration

Tags: go

I am looking at this type

```
type GzipResponseWriter struct {
    gw *gzip.Writer
    http.ResponseWriter
}
```

And functions that will implement it

```
func (w GzipResponseWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    if _, ok := w.Header()["Content-Type"]; !ok {
        // If content type is not set, infer it from the uncompressed body.
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", http.DetectContentType(b))
    }
    return w.gw.Write(b)
}

func (w GzipResponseWriter) Flush() {
    w.gw.Flush()
    if fw, ok := w.ResponseWriter.(http.Flusher); ok {
        fw.Flush()
    }
}
```

Does the http.ResponseWriter relate to the second field?
 Why not 
gw1 http.ResponseWriter?

Comment: It's an *embedded* field. Embedded fields allow for *promoting* the methods of their types to the embedding type, this is useful when you need to implement only a subset of the desired interface. If you do `gw1 http.ResponseWriter` then that becomes a plain field and none of `http.ResponseWriter`'s methods get promoted so you end up having to implement *every* method of the desired interface.

Comment: You can find more info on embedded fields [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) and [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).